# How get value of computed observable into observableArray()?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to compute some value and bind it together to UI as well as observableArray(). The problem is that I do not really have idea how to do it. I did tried use this code, but with no success. Here is **kodg** is parameter that I'm using to build root to api action that must return needed value and **books** is observableArray() that binded to UI.

```
function GrafikViewModel(grafikUri) {
        var self = this;
        self.kodg = ko.observable();
        //Getting parameter
        var kod = self.kodg();
        //Passing parameter to api
        var paxuri = '/api/orders/GetPax/' + kod;
        self.getPax = ko.computed(function () {
            $.getJSON(paxuri, function (data) {
                self.getPax(data);
            });
        });
        //How include computed values into array?
        self.books = ko.observableArray(); 
        $.getJSON(grafikUri, function (data) {
            self.books(data.$values);
        });
    }
```

Here is the HTML that must contain computed value.

```
<td>
<input type="text" id="left" class="form form-control" data-bind="value: $data.getPax" /></td>
```

**UPDATE**. Ok, I found some solution that allow to get computed value, but this value still not binding to UI.

```
function GrafikViewModel(grafikUri) {
            var self = this;
            self.books = ko.observableArray();
            self.PaxLeft = ko.computed(function() {
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.books(), function(book) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/api/orders/getpax/' + book.kodg,
                        dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function (msg) {
                            return msg.d;
                        }
                    });
                }, GrafikViewModel)});
            $.getJSON(grafikUri, function (data) {
                self.books(data.$values);
            });
        }
```

**msg.d** should be the computed value that bind to UI via self.PaxLeft, but it's not.

Comment: Why do you need two ajax calls ?

Comment: What is the aim of each ajax call ?

Comment: They are calling different API's.

Comment: Actually, the purpose of second ajax call - real time information about available pax: get real time availability information, then include this info in observable that belong to observable array and update UI. First and main ajax call getting information about product.

Comment: And one more question here - seemed like self.kodg is not initialized at the moment, but why?

Comment: The ko.computed is a single value. So if you set a variable = msg.d and return that to the computed (outside of your array), the computed will still only be set to the last value returned from your arrayForEach. Can you post a fiddle with sample data for those ajax calls?

Comment: Here is nothing to post in fact, this return simpale values - Int16, whithout any json wrapper.

Comment: Or say another words - there are many api calls but results od that call not joined into array and this is the reason probably.

Answer (score 0):

> How include computed values into array?

To include a computed within an observableArray I just build an array from another viewmodel. Then you can add a ko.computed function to that View Model. Something like this:

```
var GrafikViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Books = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(data.books, function (item) {
            return new BooksViewModel(item);
        }));
};

var BooksViewModel = function(data){
    var self = this;    
    self.MyComputed = ko.computed(function(){
        // do something
    });
};
```